Can this problem be solved using convex optimization?
I have the following problem:
$$\begin{align}
\max & \quad \frac{\mu^\top x - c^\top|x - x_0|}{x^{\top}\Sigma x} \tag{1} \\
\text{subject to } 
& \quad x \leq \mathbb{1} \tag{2}\\
& \quad x \geq -\mathbb{1} \tag{3}\\ 
& \quad |x|_1 \leq 1 \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, $x_0$ is a vector of constants, and $c_i > 0$ for all $i$.
Using linear fractional programming and relaxing constraint $(4)$, I converted the above problem minimization problem below, but I'm not sure if my treatment of $w_0$ is correct since it's inside an absolute value sign.
$$\begin{align}
\min &\quad  y^{\top}\Sigma y \tag{5}\\
\text{subject to }  
& \quad \mu^\top y - c^\top | y - w_0| = 1 \tag{6} \\
& \quad y \leq t \\
& \quad y \geq -t \\
\end{align}
$$
Ignoring the absolute value in $(6)$, I can simplify to this
$$\begin{align}
\min &\quad  y^{\top}\Sigma y \\
\text{subject to }  
& \quad (\mu - c)^\top y + c^\top x_0 t = 1 \\
& \quad y \leq t \\
& \quad y \geq -t \\
\end{align}
$$
This can be solved, but its solution has nothing to do with the original problem unfortunately.
In any case, I'm very new to quadratic / linear programming and I'm not sure if the problem is even solvable. I've been mostly using Cvxpy package to trying things. If it is solvable, I would appreciate any help I can get.

What do you mean by $| x |{1}=1$?  Do you mean that the sum of the absolute values of the entries in $x$ is one (i.e. $| x |{1}=1$)?

Yes, that’s correct. L1 norm of vector x is equal to 1

Unfortunately, $| x |{1}=1$ is a non-convex constraint, so your problem can't be addressed by convex optimization.  Would $| x |{1} \leq 1$ be sufficient?

Yes, actually that’s better — I was going to solve the less or equal to 1 case to afterwards. The L1 norm equality I had in the question was an intermediate step I set for myself

This is not a convex problem. In fact, I don't think it even has a problem. Think about the special case where $x\in{\mathbb R}^1$, then your problem has the form
$$\begin{align}
\max & \quad \frac{\mu}{\Sigma x} + \frac{c}{\Sigma}\frac{|x - x_0|}{x} \tag{1} \\
\text{subject to } 
& \quad -1 \leq x \leq \mathbb{1} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Here, unless $\mu=0$, the first term in the objective function is unbounded and at $x=0$ the objective function is infinite -- which clearly is a maximum, but not you probably want.
In higher dimensions, the situation is similar: for the zero vector, you get an infinite objective function if you let $x$ approach the origin along a direction where $x$ is not perpendicular to $\mu$.

My apologies, I made a serious transcription error in my question that reading your answer made me realize. The sign in front of $c/\Sigma$ should be negative. I've updated the question to reflect this change.

@ronburgundy But that doesn't change anything. I can still make the first term infinite at $x=0$. It only changes something if you choose $c>\mu$ and $x_0=0$, in which case you get a negative infinity at that point.

Looking at the comments to the question, I believe the original constraint was $||x||=1$. This would exclude the zero vector as an option, but make the problem non-convex.
Reverting the constraints to the original form also doesn't resolve the issue Prof. Bangerth pointed out. It just makes it harder to identify. If the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite, then for some $||x||=1$ we will have  $x^T\Sigma x = 0$. In any small neighborhood of $x$, the behaviour of the objective function will depend on $\mu$, $c$ and $x_0$.
For example, if $x_0 = \vec{0}$ then the objective value will tend to infinity if $c < \mu$, will tend to zero if $c =\mu$ and will tend to negative infinity if $c > \mu$.
If $x_0 \neq \vec{0}$ but $||x_0|| = 1$ (e.g. $x_0$ is a potential solution) and $x_0^T\Sigma x_0 \neq 0$, then the situation is even weirder. Assume that there is a vector $x^*$ such that $||x^*-x_0|| = 2$ and ${x^*}^T\Sigma x^* = 0$. If $2c < \mu$, the objective value will tend to infinite around $x^*$. Looking at the objective function, I feel that the intention is to find the closest $x$ to $x_0$ which satisfies some constraints. However, this formulation is almost ``incentivized'' to find the furthest possible point to $x_0$ within the feasible region, but only sometimes.
I think you need to go back to the drawing board and reconsider your model. I don't think even if it was somehow solvable, it would give you the results you want.
